# Windows Server 08 mysqldump variable filename using timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a batchfile that does a mysqldump with a timestamp filename.

I have tried:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword database > C:\backup\%DATE%.sql
```

I get error:

```
C:\backup\06/18/13.sql
```

Which gives me an error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Which I assume is because of the forward slashes.  I've tried using set to set DATE and then invoke it in the mysqldump line, but then batch file crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Try (`mysqlbackup.bat`):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%")  do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

mysqldump -uuser -ppassword database > C:\backup\%mydate%_%mytime%.sql
```

Courtesy to https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/1920232

Comment: Thanks it woks for me Great  Help !